# How do I set a tab for tabpane in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to create a button in my tabpane, that can switch to another tab(0 → 1).

This is for creating a chat program using Javafx, and I'm currently using Scenebuilder to design the GUI.

```
myTabPane_1.getSelectionModel().select(1);
```

I expect it to change from tab index # '0' to index # '1', but it stays the same.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

There is something that you are not showing in your code and because you did not supply enough information no one will be able to help you modify your code so here is a working example of how to change tabs using index and by passing the actual tab

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Tab tabOne = new Tab("Tab One", new Label("This is Tab One"));
        Tab tabTwo = new Tab("Tab Two", new Label("This is Tab Two"));

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tabOne, tabTwo);

        vBox.getChildren().add(tabPane);

        Button button = new Button("Change Tab by passing index");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().equals("Tab One"))
                tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(1);
            else
                tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(button);

        Button buttonTwo = new Button("Change Tab by passing tab");
        buttonTwo.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().equals("Tab One"))
                tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tabTwo);
            else
                tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tabOne);
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(buttonTwo);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```